# Difference between PHP default PDF and FPDF

Tags: php, pdf, pdf-generation, tcpdf, fpdf

I am trying out `PDF` creation in my project. My problem statement is *"to club a couple of pdf's into one single pdf"*

I want to know why people are preferring FPDF everywhere.

Doesn't PHP's default PDF module supports the same problem?

Is there any difference is speed of creation or size of file created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default PDF lib built in to PHP has limited formatting requirements such as simple text, images, colors and can become quite verbose to use.

The reason for FPDF's popularity is its high-level abstractions which make coding quicker and more concise.

Furthermore, there are numerous libraries that build on top of FPDF further.  For example, a common use case is to convert HTML markup to PDF, thus eliminating the need to get into formatting, pagination, etc.

You may find these references helpful:
- http://www.refulz.com/generate-pdf-with-php-fpdf-tcpdf-dompdf-ezpdf-fpdi-and-html2pdf/
- http://www.fpdf.org/

Answer (score 0):

PHP does not have a 'default pdf module'.